# Is TIA/similar Acceptable In A Question?

Tags: discussion

I've seen some people edit out portions of questions such as:

> Any help would be appreciated.
>
> Thanks in Advance.

Should we actively remove this content? I suppose it's in the spirit of brevity that we would do so, but I can see reasons not to as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I just found out in looking through the [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help) that this behavior is explicitly discouraged and removal is recommended.

From [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

> **Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.**
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.
>
> Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

Answer (score 14):

I think it is a best practice to remove a not relevant information from the question like *signatures*, *thank-you's*, *personal website-url or e-mail* or something like that. All that information belongs to the user's profile and could be easily found there if needed.

The content of the question should be clear and understandable from the first look without any "garbage" in it.

Some quotes from the [welcome tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) to back this up:

> - With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed
>   answers to every question about Salesforce.
> - Ask questions, get answers, no distractions. This site is all about
>   getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.
> - Use edits to fix mistakes, improve formatting, or clarify the meaning of a post.

Comment: Also, just from a quality standpoint, it lowers SEO and findability of the questions themselves

Answer (score 3):

My personal policy, as someone who edits a *lot* on many sites on the network, and whose contribution to some sites is only edits, is to remove these only if I also find something else to edit at the same time. There usually is.