# Is it ok to ask "Beginner" / "How to" questions?

Tags: support

In my opinion, the official Salesforce developer forum and tutorials pages for topics like the mobile sdk seems to be a very frustrating experience for advanced developers that are new to the salesforce ecosystem.

That's why I ask "a lot of" beginner and "how to" questions in this Stackoverflow board.

Should I avoid them in future posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly acceptable to ask beginner questions, or even how to questions. The key is to demonstrate that you have done what you can to research the problem. If you are asking "How do I write a trigger?" or "How do I unit test this code?" then your level of research is not up to the standards of this community.

All of you questions so far have received upvotes, so the community has accepted your questions well so far. One minor suggestion is that [adding thanks to your posts](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1974/2995) is somewhat off-topic and may be removed.

Anyway, you're on the right path. Cheers!